# how to understand Promise.resolve(it.throw( err )).then( handleResult)?

Tags: promise, ecmascript-6

I am reading the Chapter 4 of title 'You Don't Know JS: ES6 & Beyond'
I know what will happen with Promise.resolve(..) when passing thenable or immediate value into this static function.
But what if it goes to that `Promise.resolve(it.throw(err))` ?

The entire code which illustrates a promise + generator patter like:

```
function run(gen) {
    var args = [].slice.call( arguments, 1), it;

    it = gen.apply( this, args );

    return Promise.resolve()
        .then( function handleNext(value){
            var next = it.next( value );

            return (function handleResult(next){
                if (next.done) {
                    return next.value;
                }
                else {
                    return Promise.resolve( next.value )
                        .then(
                            handleNext,
                            function handleErr(err) {
                                return Promise.resolve(
                                    it.throw( err )
                                )
                                .then( handleResult );
                            }
                        );
                }
            })( next );
        } );
}
```

My main problem is the rejection handler - `function handleErr(err){..}`
How does it work and what will happen if promise chain keeps going.

Comment: It's for the case when the `it` generator `yield`s from a `catch` statement. Admittedly, it should just have been `return handleResult(it.throw(err))`, there's no point in placing the `Promise.resolve`/`then` in there.

Comment: @Bergi -- there is absolutely a point in placing it there. that's on purpose, not a mistake. calling `handleResult(it.throw(err))` calls it right now during this tick, but we don't want that, we want it on the next tick, which is why it's wrapped in a `Promise.resolve` and deferred to the next tick via `.then`.

Comment: @KyleSimpson: Do coroutines really care that much about ticks? But even if they do, it does not matter for `handleResult as, `handleNext`/`handleErr` that advance the generator are called asynchronously in any case.

Comment: @Bergi- I'm the one who designed this code. I want to make sure there's another tick that goes by between when `handleErr()` is run and when `handleResult()` is (re)run. You can disagree with that design and suggest your own alternate, but I stand by my objection to calling it pointless, as if it was a mistake or oversight. It's intentional.

Comment: @Bergi- Oh, and btw, just so we're absolutely accurate here, when I'm saying "tick", or when you're saying "called asynchronously", it's not actually meant that another tick of the event loop happens. It's only meant that the microtask is scheduled at the end of the queue for this tick. So even though I'm intentionally adding an extra scheduling deferral, it's still all on the same tick, at the very end.

Answer (score 2):

> But what if it goes to that `Promise.resolve(it.throw(err))`?

The result of `it.throw(..)` is an IteratorResult object: `{ value: .., done: true }`, just the same as from `it.next(..)`. I'm wrapping that object up in a promise with `Promise.resolve(..)`, so that object value is passed back into `handleResult(..)` when the `.then(handleResult)` is executed **on the next tick**.

The reason for not just doing `return handleResult(it.throw(err))`, as suggested in the comment by @Bergi, is because that would execute `handleResult(..)` on this tick, which is not what we want (for call-stack purposes).

> `function handleErr(err){..}` How does it work and what will happen if promise chain keeps going.

`handleErr(..)` is only called if the `next.value` (which is lifted via `Promise.resolve(next.value)`) is a promise that eventually gets rejected. So for example:

```
run(function*(){
   yield Promise.reject(42);
});
```

Here, the rejected promise is in `next.value` that came back from the first `it.next(..)` call, so `Promise.resolve(next.value)` just keeps it as a rejected promise, and `then(handleNext,handleErr)` causes `handleErr(..)` to be invoked with the rejected `42` value.

Now, `it.throw(err)` tries to throw this exception value (`42`) back into the generator, in case some waiting `try..catch` inside the generator would capture it.

For example, if our generator did have a `try..catch`, like this:

```
run(function*(){
   try {
      yield Promise.reject(42);
   }
   catch (err) {
      return 10;
   }
});
```

...then the `42` exception would be caught, and then `return 10` would happen. Thus, the `it.throw(..)` call would return normally with `{ value: 10, done: true }`.

Now, `Promise.resolve(..)` would lift that into a normal fulfilled promise, and `handleResult(..)` would be called, on the next tick, with that object as its `next` parameter. The `if (next.done)` passes, and `return next.value` returns `10` back, which is returned back through the recursive promise chain until finally resolving in the outermost promise that the original call to `run(..)` returned.

However, since our original generator did **not** have a `try..catch`, when `it.throw(next.value)` happens, the exception it threw in comes right back out, which abnormally aborts the current `handleErr(..)` call. Since `handleErr(..)` was initiated by `then(..)`, `then(..)` lifts that exception into a rejected promise, which is returned back through the recursive promise chain, finally rejecting the outermost promise that the original call to `run(..)` returned.